# javascript array order value from big to small

Tags: javascript, html

I just new for learning about javascript and i learn from http://www.w3schools.com. I want to ask something about array in javascript.
I try this code from that website.

Try it

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var index;
    var text = "<ul>";
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    for (index = 0; index < fruits.length; index++) {
        text += "<li>" + fruits[index] + "</li>";
    }
    text += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
```

and the result is :Banana,Orange,Apple,Mango.

and what i want to ask is, how to change value so the result can be : Mango, Apple, Orange, Banana? .I really confused to make the "FOR" condition. Thank you so much guys. I still beginner for programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just iterate from end to start:

```
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var index;
    var text = "<ul>";
    var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
    for (index = fruits.length-1; index >= 0; index--) {
        text += "<li>" + fruits[index] + "</li>";
    }
    text += "</ul>";
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this.

Use `.reverse()`

```
<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.reverse();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = fruits;

</script>
```

Fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/87pguc5a/1/

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use for loop to get your aim, you can use:

```
for (index = fruits.length-1; index >= 0; index--) {
    text += "<li>" + fruits[index] + "</li>";
}
```

Firstly, the index should be the last index of fruits, because the first index is from 0 in the array, the last index should be the length minus 1;
secondly, set the range of index should be bigger than 0 or equal to 0;
finally, the index should minus itself after one loop.

That's the way to reverse array by using for loop.

Mr Srinivas Pai's way is the simplest, but it changes the contents in fruits array.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom sort like so

```
var fruits = ["Banana", "Orangedgsdfjkl", "Apple", "Mango"];
document.getElementById("stringSort").innerHTML = fruits;

function stringLength( value1 , value2 ) {
    // Convert to string and extract the length:
    value1 = value1.toString().length;
    value2 = value2.toString().length;
    return value1>value2 ? 1 : ( value1<value2 ? -1 : 0 );
}

fruits = fruits.sort(stringLength);
document.getElementById("stringSort").innerHTML = fruits;
```

Here is the jsFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/87pguc5a/2/

Answer (score 0):

Useful array methods for JavaScript:

[link to w3](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp)